# Backend for an Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, web-services, rest, jersey

I am developing a system including an iOS and Android app. I have two approach:

1 - I thought about use MySQL as the backend.
And then use [REST in java using jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) to transfer my resources to the apps.

2 - Currently I heard about [Parse](https://parse.com/) which is consider as a easy way to add a backend to the mobile applications. It lets the mobile developers write server code without servers.

Which one is your suggestion? please support your answer with proper reasons and your personal experience.

Comment: What kind of data will your backend have?

Comment: I need to Save arbitrary data, Save photos and other files. Create user accounts and Add Facebook Login. I think they have all supported by `parse`, but by the way I want to know about advantage and dis-advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I participated in the development of an iOS/Android app. We used a server coded in java working as a web service running on Tomcat 7, with a mongoDB database, and JSON parsing for communication. Certainly not the best solution ever, but it was working.

Comment: Thanks, Can I know about your server? How you lunch your java code (perhaps in Eclipse) running on Tomcat in the Server?

Comment: I did not work that much on the server, but I can tell you that we developed it in Eclipse, exported it as a war, then Tomcat has a web interface where you send the file and it starts the server with a specific address (for example localhost:8080/myserver if you're running local). Does it answer your question at all ?

Comment: Well, I know how to run it on localhost, I want to know about your real server. How you set your database and Web Service there?

Comment: We ran a linux ubuntu and installed tomcat and mongoDB, uploaded our .war locally in tomcat. Our java server automatically created the collection and the tables in mongo.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly what I needed, because I need to hear an experience from `Parse` but by the way `+1` for you that share your experience with me. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it's just my own experience, certainly not the best thing there is... I also heard Parse is pretty good. Ray Wenderlich has a pretty good tutorial on Parse : http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1 (this is the first part, you'll find the second one at the end of the tutorial). Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be trendy, use node.js and MongoDB. (Although MongoDB is not trendy anymore, but it allows binary files of arbitrary length and works beautifully.) PHP with MongoDB works fine too.

My reasons: they are widespread technologies and with a very low barrier of entry. Avoid Java unless you want to nurse your JVM.

Comment: You are welcome. Let us know what you choose, even if you have to answer your own question.

Comment: how would an ios app communicate with a node.js server, through parse? or are there other ways?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your typical backend for a mobile app which involves one or more REST apis and provides server-side functionality such as user authentication, communication (e.g. chat, messaging), or persistence (e.g. a leaderboard for a game, or retrieving geo-location related data). You basically have the two options you mentioned, build yourself or use a backend-as-a-service platform.

**Build yourself (pros):**

- You retain all of the IP
- You have the best level of customization

**Build yourself (cons):**

- Very high learning curve if you lack server-side coding experience
- Longer to implement, and harder to iterate quickly if you need to change something or add a feature
- Higher risk of critical issues if you lack experience (e.g. security vulnerabilities, reliability etc)
- You need to monitor and maintain the system once it's deployed. This can become a full time job if the app gets big enough

**Backend-as-a-service platform (pros):**

- Much faster to get something up and running. This is a big one if you're launching something new and want to validate the market
- Benefit from the years of experience of server-side developers who built the platform
- Often, platforms will provide ready-made components that already do what you need
- Running and operating the backend is included as part of the service, you don't need to worry about it.
- It's actually cheaper than implementing it yourself if you consider the time investment, or if you hire a backend developer to build it for you
- It allows you to focus your energy and time on the client side app, which is where you'll most likely differentiate yourself anyway

**Backend-as-a-service platform (cons):**

- You have less flexibility, depending on the platform (some are better than others)
- There's usually a recurring cost (although you'll also incur some of this if you build it yourself, to run the servers and databases)
- There's always a risk that the provider will shut down (like Parse) and you're left scrambling to find an alternative or rebuild it yourself

There are now many backend-as-a-service platforms available to chose from. Unfortunately, Parse is no longer one of them, having been acquired by Facebook and subsequently shut down https://www.computerworld.com/article/3027537/application-development/facebook-is-closing-down-its-parse-developer-platform.html

I feel that a backend-as-a-service platform is a good option if you don't have much experience on the server side, or if you have limited time and want to focus your attention on the client side app. One of the greatest benefits is fast iteration. You can try something out and change it quickly with relatively little investment if you realize that your feature didn't hit the mark. Some examples of backend service providers can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service.

Some of the platforms actually allow you to build a full custom app without actually writing any code, and some of them provide ready-made components (like chat, leaderboards etc) but are less flexible.

Here's a list of Backend-as-a-service providers:

- http://pipegears.com (No coding required)
- https://www.appcelerator.com/
- https://cloudboost.io/
- http://api.shephertz.com/
- https://backendless.com/
- https://quickblox.com/